# Mail results from a form

Tags: php, html, email

I have three Files. The index, which is holding my form. The checkout.php which has the breakdown of the items selected, and a form with some information. My last file is email.php which has the code to email the results. I am trying to have the breakdown portion emailed so i know what that person wants.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mid-Night Designs Quote</title>
 
    <!--Required-->
 <script src="js-assets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js-assets/cost_calculator.js"></script>
    <!--/Required-->
    
 <link href='default-styles.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style type="text/css">
 body,td,th {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<!--Quick Reference

- Each row should have these data tags: 'data-row', 'data-value'
- Each row required the class 'cost_calc_calculate'
- Optional data tags: 'data-show', 'data-id', 'data-select'
- Optional classes: 'single'

- 'data-row' is the individual row, you can have multiple items attached to the data row, think of it as a group or a section for your pricing.

- 'data-value' is the cost of the item they have selected, this is used to add to your calculated cost. You can leave 'data-value' blank if you like, but when they click the item it will revert to the default message you set in the 'cost_calculator.js' file. If you want the value to be 0, just simply put "0" instead of nothing.

-'data-show' will show a row that you have hidden with the 'cost_calc_hide' class, this is good to use when you only want a certain row to show for a certain option.
Explained: If you put 'data-show="2"'. This will show any row with the value of "2" on the 'data-row'

-'data-id' should be unique to every item, don't repeat it.

-'data-select' is used to automatically select an item with the 'data-id' value you enter.

-The class 'single' will only let one option in that row be choosen at a time. If this class is not applied, the user will be able to select multple options in a row.

You can see a full working example below. Enjoy and I hope you enjoy this simple, yet powerful plugin.

/Quick Reference-->
    
<div class="container clearfix">
    
    <h1>Mid-Night Designs</h1>
    
    <p>
       
       <h3><a  href='http://mid-nightdesigns.com'>Back to Mid-Night Designs</a></h3>
    </p><center>
    *This quote calculator isn't 100% accurate and may vary*
    <p></p></center>
    
    <form method="post">
    <h3>Step 1: Select A Website Style</h3>
    <!-- Price Button(data-value is the price assigned to the button)-->
        <!--Row 1-->
  <!--This is a default price that'll always be applied-->
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-1 single cost_calc_calculate " value="Simple Website" 
               data-row='1' 
               data-id='1' 
               data-select='2'
               data-value="100">
  <!--/-->
 
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-1 cost_calc_calculate single " value="Advanced Website" 
               data-row='1' 
               data-select='2'
               data-value="250">
               
        <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-1 cost_calc_calculate single " value="eCommerce" 
               data-row='1' 
               data-select='2'
               data-value="320">     
               
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-1 cost_calc_calculate single " value="Blog" 
               data-row='1' 
               data-select='2'
               data-value="420">
        
        <h3>Step 2: How Many Static Pages Do You Need?</h3>
  <!--Row 2-->
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="1 Page" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-id='2'
               data-value="60">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="2 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="80">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="3 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="100">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="4 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="120">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="5 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="140">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="6 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="160">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="7 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="180">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="8 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="200">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="9 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="220">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="10 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="250">

  <!--If the data-value is equal to nothing, you'll be shown the default "more" field-->
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="10-20 Pages" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-value="410">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-2 cost_calc_calculate single " value="Not Sure?" 
               data-row='2' 
               data-value="none">
  <!--/-->
  <h3>Step 3: How Many Dynamic Pages Do You Need? (Database cost has been included in every page)</h3>
     <p>
     <!--Row 3-->
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="1 Dynamic Page & Database" 
               data-row='3' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-id='5'
               data-value="400">
     
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="2 Dynamic Pages" 
               data-row='3' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="400">
     
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="3 Dynamic Pages" 
               data-row='3' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="400">
  </p>
     <p>
       
          <h3>Step 4: Choose A Content Management System</h3>
     <p>
     <!--Row 3-->
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="Admin CMS" 
               data-row='4' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-id='5'
               data-value="550">
     
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="Basic In-Browser Editing" 
               data-row='4' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="0">
     
     <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-3 cost_calc_calculate single " value="We Manage" 
               data-row='4' 
               data-select='1' 
               data-value="50/Mo">
  </p>
     <p>
        
        
        <h3>Step 5: Choose A Desired Time Frame</h3>
     <p>
     <!--Row 3-->
     <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Durations" 
               data-row='4' 
               data-value="0" 
               data-show="5">
  </p>
     <p>
          
           <!--Row 4, this row is hidden until "Quick turn around" is clicked, note the use of 'data-show' on that item above-->
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate single cost_calc_hide" value="5 Days" 
               data-row='5' 
               data-value="999">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate single cost_calc_hide" value="7 Days" 
               data-row='5' 
               data-value="599">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate single cost_calc_hide" value="2 Weeks" 
               data-row='5' 
               data-value="299">
    
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate single cost_calc_hide" value="5 Weeks" 
               data-row='5' 
               data-value="0">

          
       <!--/--></p>
     <h3>Step 6: Any Additional Services?</h3>
  <!--Row 4-->
  <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Search Engine Optimization" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="250">
    
  <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Mobile & Tablet Design" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="130">
    
   <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Email Address (1)" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="60/Yr">
                                      
        <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Payment Integration" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="20">
               
               <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Advertisements(2)" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="10">
    
  <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Search Box" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="50">
    
   <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="User Registration" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="200">
                                      
        <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Forum" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="260">
                      
                      
        <input type="button" class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Social Media Links" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="0">
    
  <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Multimedia" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="25">
    
   <input type="button"  class="cost_calc_row-4 cost_calc_calculate " value="Forms, Surveys, And Polls" 
               data-row='6' 
               data-value="30">
                                  
        </form>                                  
 <!--/-->
 
    
       
 <!--Clear Calculations-->
    <br>
  <div id='cost_calc_clear_calculation' class="hover">Clear selections</div>
    
 <!--Total and breakdown-->
    <div id="cost_calc_breakdown_container" class="clearfix">
        <p class="cost_calc_heading">
        Total cost:<br />
        </p>
        <p id="cost_calc_total_cost">
        0.00<br />
        </p>
        
        <div id="cost_calc_breakdown" class="clearfix">
        </div>
        
  <!--The form that the data is applied to.-->
        <form action="checkout.php" method="post">
   
   <!--Data applied to these field-->
            <textarea id='cost_calc_custom-data' name="cost_calc_cost_data"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id='cost_calc_price' value="" name="cost_calc_price">
   <!--/-->
   
            <input type="submit" class="cost_calc_button" value="Start Now!">
        </form>
    </div>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Getting Started</title>
 
    <!--Validator (optional)-->
 <script src="js-assets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js-assets/simple_validate.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        simple_form_validator (
        'This field is required.',      //Standard input message (.validate)
        'Your email address is required.',    //Email input message (.validate_email)
        'Your phone number is required.',    //Phone number message (.validate_phone)
        'Please select an answer.',     //Radio box message (.validate_radio)
        'Please accept the terms and condtions.',   //Checkbox message (.validate_checkbox)
        '10',           //Minimum amount of digitals required for phone number
        '12'           //Maximum amount of digitals required for phone number

        //Please note, to style the required messages, just add your CSS to the class "validate_form_message".
        );
    });
    </script>
    <!--/Validator-->
    
 <link href='default-styles.css' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    //Price
    $full_cost = $_POST['cost_calc_price'];

    //Build breakdown
    $breakdown = $_POST['cost_calc_cost_data'];
    $breakdown = str_replace('d1','<p class="cost_calc_item_name">',$breakdown);
    $breakdown = str_replace('d2','</p>',$breakdown);
    $breakdown = str_replace('d3','<p class="cost_calc_item_price">&#36;',$breakdown);
    $breakdown = str_replace('d4','</p>',$breakdown);

    //Build description
    $description = $_POST['cost_calc_cost_data'];
    $description = str_replace('d1','',$description);
    $description = str_replace('d2','',$description);
    $description = str_replace('d3','- ',$description);
    $description = str_replace('d4',' | ',$description);
?>

<div class='cost_calc_quote_summary clearfix'>
    <h2>Cost Breakdown</h2>
    <?php echo $breakdown; ?>
    <div class='cost_calc_breakdown_total'>Total: &#36;<?php echo $full_cost; ?></div>
</div>

<div class='cost_calc_checkout_form clearfix'>
<form method="post" name="formdata" action="email.php">
    <h2>Information</h2>
        
            <label>
                Email Address
                <input class="SV_validate_email" type="text" NAME="email" placeholder="Email Address">
            </label>

            <label>
                First Name
                <input class="SV_validate" type="text" NAME="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
            </label>

            <label>
                Last Name
                <input class="SV_validate" type="text" NAME="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
            </label>

            <label>
                Phone Number
                <input class="SV_validate_phone" NAME="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
            </label>
             <input type="submit" NAME="submit" value="PURCHASE">
        </div>
    </form>
    <!--End Form-->
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = ""; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $phonenumber = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject = "Quote Submission from " . $first_name. $last_name. $phonenumber;
    $subject2 = "Mid-Night Designs Quote Results for" . $first_name;
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST[''];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: The email doesn't contain the breakdown data. It's just blank.

Comment: In $message you send $_POST[''], so it's basically nothing and in $message2 you send $_POST['message'], but there isn't any field of that name in checkout.php...

Comment: @JanRydrych so how would I get it to send this information "<div class='cost_calc_quote_summary clearfix'>     <h2>Cost Breakdown</h2>     <?php echo $breakdown; ?>     <div clas" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all data from the form to the string fo PHP mail function (string can contain plaintext or HTML formated message body)

So for example:

```
checkout.php:
....
count value from index.html form into $counted_value
....
<form.....
....
<input type="hidden" name="countedvalue" value="<?php echo $counted_value;?>"
</form>

email.php:
$message = 'User posted: \n'.
    'email: '.$_POST['email'].
    ', first name: '.$_POST['first_name'].
    ', last name: '.$_POST['last_name'].
    ', phone: '.$_POST['phone'].
    ', value: '.$_POST['countedvalue'];
mail($to, $subj, $message);
```

Comment: Not quiet what I'm needing. I need the information from the breakdown to be in the message so when I receive the email I know what they selected and the price it costed

Comment: Aaaha, you told, that your problem is message is blank... So you have to process first form in checkout.php, then put the counted value info hidden filed in form on checkout.php and then include that field into message string...

Comment: Not good with words :/ But I just want the information that was selected in the message

Comment: I'm sorry. No. Where am I putting this information ?

Comment: Simply said - html or PHP does not do any counting work for you. So if user submits the form, you have to get values from $_POST variable and do things what you need. If you need to pass values from index.html form through checkout.php into email.php you have to pass if through some variable and hidden field.